# How to use computer as server to run an app locally to show on my android tablet?

Tags: android, mysql, webserver, localhost

I have an app that currently runs on a wamp server on my computer because it uses sql databases. I want a way to see the application (including the sql databases data) on my tablet. It just needs to be a local connection. When I download the app at the moment, I see the app but it doesn't show the sql databases. How can I setup so that the tablet uses the computer as a server to view everything?

Answer (score 0):

You may try native web servers for Android, like [kWS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb)